# useContext not reading values on first refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-context

```
export const LoginContext = React.createContext();
export const DetailsContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const username = localStorage.getItem("bankDetails");
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});
  const [isValid, setisValid] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (username !== null) {
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/userDetails", {
        username: username,
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.err) {
          console.log("err");
        } else {
          setUserDetails(res.data.details[0]);
          setisValid(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider value={{ isValid, setisValid }}>
      <DetailsContext.Provider value={{ userDetails, setUserDetails }}>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route ... />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </DetailsContext.Provider>
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Transactions.js

```
function Transactions() {
  const { isValid } = useContext(LoginContext);
  const { userDetails, setUserDetails } = useContext(DetailsContext);
  const [allDetails, setAllDetails] = useState([]);
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userDetails);
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/transactTo").then((rest) => {
      setAllDetails(rest.data);
    });
    // setTransactions(JSON.parse(userDetails.transactions));
  }, [userDetails]);

  return isValid ? <h1>Valid</h1> : <h1>Not Valid</h1>
}
export default Transactions;
```

The `userDetails` logs an empty object first and data object after re-render but after uncommenting the `setTransactions(JSON.parse(userDetails.transactions))` part it only logs an empty object and then an error stating: `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`. It only happens on page refresh and not when I navigate from another page.

Also tried adding second effect but it didn't helped:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTransactions(JSON.parse(userDetails.transactions));
}, [allDetails]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an empty object because API requests are asynchronous. It is a normal thing.

`Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` this means that `userDetails.transactions` isn't a json. It's probably `undefined` that's why `u`

```
useEffect(() => {
  // try returning when the property is `undefined`
  if (!userDetails.transations) return;
  setTransactions(JSON.parse(userDetails.transactions));
}, [allDetails]);
```

Comment: I need to get rid of the error